QGIS fill individual sink
I’m trying to determine the maximum extent of a pond when it is filled to its maximum capacity.
I think this is the same logic as the sink filling algorithms used for hydraulically correct dem’s - but I can’t work out how to apply the same logic to a single sink.
The ideal output would be a vector polygon at the maximum contour level before water would spill out of the pond.

Do all depressions and delete all, but one

What about filling sinks and then differencing the rasters. Unless the pond was already full, non-zero areas would delineate the extent of the pond. Obviously this would identify all "ponds" not just the one you are looking for, but I think any automated approach would have this issue.

Hi Tom - I had this thought too to determine the extent. Also about limiting the original dem to only contain one ‘pond’. My research around sink filling algorithms seems to indicate there is usually a seed point (usually a cell with no lower neighbours). I wondered if I could manually add the seed point and grow to the pond extent

I don't think there is a specific maximum capacity to the pond, except if the pond is artificial and not natural.
If the pond is artificial then its pretty easy to create a polygon at its perimeter regarding that you know the depth of the pond.
If the pond is natural, then the maximum capacity depends on the return period of a flood event.
If you have a specific hydrological scenario with a specific return period then you can run the HEC-RAS for this scenario and see the flooded extent, and then base with that extent see the maximum capacity.

Perhaps I wasn’t clear - I’m looking for the theoretical maximum ‘specific natural capacity’ (or the contour polygon representing the highest level on a stage-storage curve). The pond might be half full in a dem - what would be the highest water surface level before it overflows?

I might be missing something, but I think there will always be a maximum capacity to either an artificial or a natural depression- think for example of an upland glacially-scoured lake. Water will overflow when the level reaches the minimum confining elevation- which might be a wall formed by a terminal morrain or the lowest point on a bounding ridge. Either way, you can calculate the capacity of the depression within the confining minimum contour but the capacity will be higher if the "wall" is raised.

@Leigh Bettany - that minimum confining elevation contour level is what I’m looking for - but I want to generate it automatically, not manually select it. I’m looking for area of that contour, not capacity

The minimum confining elevation contour should be the highest closed contour. I don't known how to find this with a program but it should be evident by eye. Perhaps if you search on the reverse logic of finding peaks programmatically you might get some insight.

@tomtomnz From what i see what you want is a shape in the form of a closed polygon that will show you the maximum extent of flooded area. This area changes depending the return period of the flood event, you cant have a specific flow. This area can be produced at a software called HEC-RAS.

@dimitris I understand what your saying regarding return period. Let’s assume it’s the static state maximum level for simplicity and remove any inflow/outflow influence. Basically the highest static water level before any overflow. I’d prefer to stay within QGIS  to solve this problem
